# "Cannot call method 'ready' of undefined" error on $(document).ready

Tags: jquery

I'm calling `$(document).ready(function(){...})` in a JS file included halfway through my page's body (I know it should go at the bottom, there are reasons why it's in the middle though)

Whenever I load the page, I get in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ready' of undefined
```

The thing is, it still works! all of the code I was putting in document.ready is still (somehow) being run, and it executes perfectly. I've tried just removing the $(document).ready() line, but then the code doesn't get run.

I'm working on Mac OSX Mountain Lion, and testing in Chrome

edit:

jQuery is imported in the  tag, and everything, including jQuery is actually working, I'm just trying to get rid of the error.

edit #2:

I fixed the problem, but I really don't know what was happening.  I rewrote the function I was giving to $(document).ready(), and it started working again. I think I was using some jQuery stuff a little bit wrong, but I guess I'll never know what was really happening.

Comment: Did you import the jquery src?

Comment: make sure your jQuery lib imported. And try to change like -> `$(function(){....})`

Comment: @AldiUnanto and PRPGFerret: If `$` were completely undefined, it would be a different error.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because it didn't fit the symptom that the code *does* get run. The only thing I can think of is that there is something **else** calling a function called `ready` elsewhere, and it's *that* call, not yours, that's failing. The answer, as is frequently the case, is to debug it. Put a breakpoint on the `$(document).ready` line in the debugger built into your browser and step through the code statement by statement. (You can also insert the line `debugger;` just before it, which is a hardcoded breakpoint. The debugger will stop on it provided you have it open.)

Comment: Did you possibly include a jquery extension of some sort prior to including the jquery library itself?

Comment: In your console (Google Chrome console), find the error, then click the down arrow on the left side. Now, on the right side, you'll see where it is outputting information about how the error happened. Each line can be clicked, which will take you into the code where the error occured. Does it take you inside jQuery.js?

Comment: The error is entirely in jquery